# OnActionExecuted doesn't return response to client in webpi

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I want to log all requests (including response) sent to api controller.

```
public class LogActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        //my logic to get request and save in logs.
        var jsonBody = Utility.GetRequestJSON(actionContext);
        Utility.SaveLogAsync(jsonBody);
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionContext)
        {
            //my logic to get response and save in logs.
            string responseReturned = GetBodyFromRequest(actionContext);

            Utility.SaveLogAsync(responseReturned); //data is logged successfully but no response is returned to client.
            base.OnActionExecuted(actionContext);
        }
}
```

Here is my api controller:

```
[LogActionFilter]
    public class ServiceController : ApiController
    {
        [AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
        [HttpGet]
        [HttpPost]
        public object Login()        
        {
            var jsonBody = Utility.GetRequestJSON(HttpContext.Current);
            AccountService _accountService = new AccountService(); 
            return _accountService.Login(jsonBody, Request.GetClientIP());
        }
    }
```

If I comment `OnActionExecuted` method then response is returned fine. But with `OnActionExecuted` method no response is returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was reading response as:

```
string data;
            using (var stream = context.Response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result)
            {
                if (stream.CanSeek)
                {
                    stream.Position = 0;
                }

                data = context.Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            }
```

Response wasn't returned to client because using dispose stream.
It worked after removing `using`:

```
string data;
            var stream = context.Response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;

                if (stream.CanSeek)
                {
                    stream.Position = 0;
                }
                data = context.Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```